# Db2 storing of data encountered error of The numeric literal XXXX is not valid

Tags: python, sql, db2

I am parsing [Wikepedia1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_neighbourhoods_in_Toronto) for Neighbourhood and [Wikipedia2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexandra_Park,_Toronto)  for Neighbourhood's latitude and longitude and storing into IBM Db2. I encountered following error code. Please advise.

**Version of imports as following**

```
ibm_db 3.0.2
requests 2.24.0
bs4 4.9.1
pandas 1.0.5
```

I am able to parse until item 102 as following:

[image]

**HTML of the location where it fails:**

[image]

**Error Code**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-035d46749936> in <module>
     14         print(primary_key,";",neighbour['href'],";", neighbour['title'],";",lat, lng)
     15         insertQuery = f"insert into TORONTO values({primary_key},'{neighbour['title']}','{neighbour['href']}','{lat}','{lng}')"
---> 16         ibm_db.exec_immediate(conn,insertQuery)

Exception: [IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/LINUXX8664] SQL0103N  The numeric literal "27s_Bridge" is not valid.  SQLSTATE=42604 SQLCODE=-103
```

my Db2 table as following
`create table TORONTO(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, neighbourhood VARCHAR(20), href VARCHAR(20), latitude VARCHAR(20), longitude VARCHAR(20) )`

**My code for parsing**

```
primary_key = 0
for table in soup.find_all('table', class_ = 'multicol'):
    for neighbour in table.find_all('a', href=True, class_=False):
        url2 = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/' + neighbour['href']
        url_object = requests.get(url2)
        soup2 = BeautifulSoup(url_object.text, 'html.parser')
        count = 0
        primary_key += 1
        for coor in soup2.find_all('span', class_ = ['latitude','longitude']):
            if count == 2: continue
            if count == 0: lat = str(coor.string)
            if count == 1: lng = str(coor.string)
            count += 1
        print(primary_key,url2, neighbour['title'],lat, lng)
        insertQuery = f"insert into TORONTO values({primary_key},'{neighbour['title']}','{url2}','{lat}','{lng}')" 
        ibm_db.exec_immediate(conn,insertQuery)
```

Comment: A table named Toronto?!? Separate tables for each city is a very bad idea.

Comment: Just for a 1 time assignment. I need to find out all the Neighbor in Toronto

Comment: Please edit your question, to show the __versions__ of the components you use (and the `import ...` list in your python code), e.g. from `pip freeze` etc.

Comment: Added versions of import. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your query to:

```python
insertQuery = f"insert into TORONTO values({primary_key},'{neighbour['title']}','{url2}','{lat}','{lng}')"
```

Comment: Hi Thanks. It works. May i know why adding '' into the variable is necessary? I though all are already strings as specify by the table schema?

Comment: SQL is similar to python in that all strings need to be surrounded by quotes/apostrophes, just referencing the variable is not enough you need to hardcode in the quotes/apostrophes.

Comment: Oh understood. So even if the variable is string is still not sufficient.

Comment: Hi. I have a new error code
`[IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/LINUXX8664] SQL0103N  The numeric literal "27s_Bridge" is not valid.  SQLSTATE=42604 SQLCODE=-103`

It happen at observation #103

Comment: Are you able to share the exact SQL insert statement is is trying to run with the values instead of the variable name?

Comment: The SQL statement is in code above. The values are `neighbour['title'] ` etc are parsed from beautifulSoup. Hence it is kept as a variable..

Comment: `https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_neighbourhoods_in_Toronto` this is the page where i get all the neighborhood under `neighbhood by district` from there i gotten the `neighhood['title'] `, as well as `href` which leads me to its `lat`, and `lng`.

Comment: Where does "27s_Bridge" come from?

Comment: I have edited my original to the latest problem.